# Find (and return) range of cells containing formulae

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am working on a table where I track down a Meter value on daily basis.
Since it's not really daily updated, I use a formula to forecast the Meter value. 
Therefore the forecasted trend between the (variable) days of a manual input is not 100% reliable and made a formula where  `# m³` was calculated only if not `ISFORMULA(B#)` (see below), in order to read in column `m³` the real usage between those days.

BUT now I came to the idea to autopopulate the `m³` cells between the range with an auto-calculated daily average between the days where two values have been inserted manually.
So i came up with this draft version for column C

for C11 `=if(isformula(B11),if(isblank(C12),,if(isformula(B12),C12,"RANGE_DIFF/DAYS")),RANGE_DIFF)`

where, in this case, `RANGE_DIFF` should be`B12-B9` and `DAYS = 3`

In other words, how do I *determine and return the range* of cells between two *manually inserted* values?

[Link to sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lWSWn9rRIylOWTSmf_x5p3-dib-0vbWAFgSav0mUGA0/edit?usp=sharing)

Thanks in advance :)

```
+----------+-----------+----------+
| Date     | Meter     | m³       |
+----------+-----------+----------+
| ...      | ...       | ...      |
| 09/1     | 9,381.296 | 0.75 m³  |  <<< MANUAL INSERTION          | =IF(ISFORMULA(C9),,C9-C8)
| 10/1     | 9,382.622 |          |  <<< =TREND(B3:B9,A3:A9,A10)   | * =C11
| 11/1     | 9,383.955 |          |  <<< =TREND(B4:B10,A4:A10,A11) | * =RANGE_DIFF/DAYS
| 12/1     | 9,385.197 | ???      |  <<< MANUAL INSERTION          | *** RANGE_DIFF >>> =B12-B9
| 13/1     | 9,386.350 | 1.15 m³  |  <<< MANUAL INSERTION          | =IF(ISFORMULA(C13),,C13-C12)
| ...      | ...       | ...      |
+----------+-----------+----------+
```

[image: Spread screenshot]

Comment: Would you consider using a [custom formula](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) created in Google Apps Script?

Comment: Not really, i was wondering if there is some magic working with `SUMPRODUCT`, `INDEX` and `OFFSET` or similar functions

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the desired outcome here. Please be aware that the columns in the sample you provided don't match the ones in your explanation, which can lead to confusion. Do you want the formula to look for the closest cells that don't contain a formula, and calculate the average based on that?